# In Chatsecure conversations, what is the meaning of the little ticks and crosses?

Tags: instant-messaging, xmpp

I noticed that after each message when OTR is enabled, 2 little ticks or crosses appear in the message bubble. Sometimes they change color from black to white.

What is the meaning of these indicators?

I think it something to do with message delivery and /or to flag the recipient has read the message, but I would appreciate a definitive explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One check means it was sent.

Two check means it was delivered, though not necessarily read.

One check with One X means it was sent, but no delivery receipt was received.

Comment: And the color changes? I don't think I imagined these ... is this a GUI glitch?

Comment: There shouldn't be any color changing... can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Maybe you're right - or they could be transient. I use the dark theme and the "stable" colors are red ticks and white crosses. Maybe the crosses momentarily appear as black. Can't screenshot this as its transient!